# If $f'(t) = g'(t)$ then $f(t) = g(t) + k$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

> Let $f,g: I \to\mathbb R$ for some interval $I\subset\mathbb R$. Then $f'(t) = g'(t)$ for all $t\in I$ if and only if there exists $k\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(t) = g(t)+k$.

Necessary condition is trivial. Let's suppose then that $f,g$ are differentiable functions that satisfy $f'(t) = g'(t)$ for all $t\in I$. Then $f'(t) - g'(t)= (f-g)'(t) = 0$ and, by the definition of derivative (at $c\in I$): given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, if $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ then
$$ \left|\frac{f(x)-g(x) + g(c)-f(c)}{x-c}\right|< \varepsilon, $$
or, equivalently
$$ \left|f(x)-g(x)+g(c)-f(c)\right| < \varepsilon\delta. $$
However, I don't know how to justify that necessarily $f(t)= g(t)+k$, which makes trivially true the last inequality, since
$$ |g(x)+k-g(x)+g(c)-g(c)-k| = 0 < \varepsilon\quad \forall \varepsilon > 0\;\forall k\in\mathbb R. $$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is really classical, you should be able to find the answer in any book on differential calculus

Comment: Start by proving that a function whose derivative is zero everywhere, must be constant. (The mean value theorem will be very helpful for this.)

Comment: You might want to assume $f,g$ are differentiable on $I$ for this to be really correct. Then one direction is trivial. The other one requires the mean value theorem.

Comment: @mrf Thanks, it solved everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should add some infos, for sure you mean that $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable.
Let's say $f'(x)=g'(x)$ than we define 
$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$ 
$h$ is differentiable and 
$$h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)=0$$
With the mean value theorem we know that 
$$h(b)-h(a)=h'(\xi) \cdot (b-a)=0$$
and hence $h$ is constant

Comment: Then we take $k = 0$ for every case?

Comment: No. We know that there exists a $c$ such that $f-g=h=c$ (this is $h$ is constant) which is $f=g+c$